# Is there a better alternative to Timers to increment speed?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm making a chaser game in flash, where you would press an arrow key and the player would move in that direction then stop on another point on a grid, as the enemy does the same and chases the player. To make the movement smooth, I have a timer moving the player one pixel each repetition (50 times to stay on the grid points), having the delay get smaller every 30 frames to speed up. But after the delay gets to 0 and can't go any lower, the player can't get faster. What is a better alternative to use to continue going faster?

```
            var playerTimer:Timer=new Timer(40,50);
            playerTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,playerMoveTrigger);
            var pStatus:String="";
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,playerMove);
            function playerMove(e:KeyboardEvent):void
                {
                if((player.x+15)%50==0&&(player.y+15)%50==0)//ensures player is on grid before moving
                {
                    switch(e.keyCode)
                        {
                            case Keyboard.DOWN:
                            pStatus="down";
                            break;

                            case Keyboard.UP:
                            pStatus="up";
                            break;

                            case Keyboard.LEFT:
                            pStatus="left";
                            break;

                            case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                            pStatus="right";
                            break;
                        }
                }
                playerTimer.start()
                }
                playerTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetTimerP);
                function resetTimerP(e:TimerEvent){playerTimer.reset();}

            function playerMoveTrigger(e:TimerEvent)
            {blockMove(player,pStatus);}
            var offSet:int=0;
            function blockMove(block:Shape,dir:String)
                {   offSet=(block.height==30)?15:10;
                    switch(dir)
                        {
                            case "down":
                            if(block.y+offSet<150){block.y+=1;}
                            break;

                            case "up":
                            if(block.y+offSet>50){block.y-=1;}
                            break;

                            case "left":
                            if(block.x+offSet>50){block.x-=1;}
                            break;

                            case "right":
                            if(block.x+offSet<150){block.x+=1;}
                            break;
                        }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Increase the distance the player moves per timer iteration

Change your += or -= 1 to a variable [speed].  Your speed starts out at 1 and increases as the game progresses

Comment: Assuming I did that, increasing the speed to factors of 50 to stay on the grid, wouldn't it start to get unreasonably fast? (1,2,5,10,25,50) By 25 or 50, the movement would be nearly instant

Comment: @user99988 What's the highest level you made it to in Tetris?  "Unreasonably fast" is kind of the point.

Comment: But there's literally only 5 increments I can do in that case, isn't there a more gradual way to speed up?

Comment: @Malzzzy Two thoughts:  (1) Why can't you increment it gradually?  and (2) You could increase the timer when you jump the speed.  `speed = 25; timer.interval += 50;` and then decrease the timer again.  But still... (1)?

Comment: I guess I should have been a bit more specific in what I was looking for. I chose to use a timer so that the movement looked smooth to the player, instead of looking blocky. At a delay of 0, the timer is moving the player one pixel at a set time, is there any way go faster than that?

Comment: @Malzzzy My answer is the same... Move the player more than one pixel at a time.  Once the timer hits zero, start increasing the speed.  It's the *only* way to make the player move faster.

Comment: You can also use floating point numbers instead of purely integers.  Then you can increase speed by 1.3 or such.  You can snap positions to integers when drawing if you want to stay strictly pixel aligned.